# MVC3 - All routing works locally but not remotely

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a new MVC3 project with one Controller called PublicController.cs which contains 4 identical methods for testing out how routing works. The only difference between them is their name, and that they each point to a different view ...

```
public class PublicController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Public/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Public/App
    public ActionResult App()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Public/Press
    public ActionResult Press()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Public/Contact
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I can get to all of them when running in the development server by visiting these URLs...

```
http://localhost:53367/Public/
```

or its equivalent

```
http://localhost:53367/Public/Index
```

and then

```
http://localhost:53367/Public/App
http://localhost:53367/Public/Press 
http://localhost:53367/Public/Contact
```

However, once it's deployed to my remote ASP.NET 4.0 server, the only two that work are:

```
http://localhost:53367/Public
http://localhost:53367/Public/Index
```

... all others give me a 404 Resource cannot be found error.

My web-server is shared hosting with netcetera, using a sub-domain for this deployment (previously had problems with MVC in virtual directories, but have full blown MVC2 apps running in sub-domains no problem). I've deployed by using the "Publish to file system" option, then copying over the files aswell as just copying the entire source project over. Both give identical results.

Any ideas why?

Thanks,

Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure MVC 3 Framework is installed to the web server, and that your site's app pool is set to 4.x ASP.net?

Comment: Hey. The server is definitely set to ASP.NET 4.0, and I bin deployed MVC3 since I can't install the framework due to it being a shared server. I did it in a similar way to MVC2 which works fine on another of my domains with the same host. Thanks

Comment: Hey. I went back and looked at the bin deploy instructions I'd used, and sure enough I'd missed some DLLs out ... due to the site partially running (Public/Index) and no error messages about missing DLLs I didn't realise that was the issue! Thanks for making me think twice!